# Pandas dataframe: what is the correct use of pandas index get_loc?

Tags: python, pandas

I see in the documentation for [get_loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) that it returns:

> int if unique index, slice if monotonic index, else mask

What indexing method do you use this return type with when accessing the dataframe? `iloc`, `loc` or `[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is used with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), because it return position by label.

E.g. if need third value of column `b` you need return position of `b`, then use [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],
                   'b':[2,3,4]}, index=list('abc'))


print (df.columns.get_loc('b'))
1

out = df.iloc[2, df.columns.get_loc('b')]
print (out)
4
```

So working like:

```
out = df.iloc[2, 1]
print (out)
4
```

Similar method for working with multiple values in list is [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html):

```
print (df.columns.get_indexer(['b', 'a']))
[1 0]

out = df.iloc[2, df.columns.get_indexer(['b', 'a'])]
print (out)
b    4
a    3
Name: c, dtype: int64

out = df.iloc[2, [1, 0]]
print (out)
b    4
a    3
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Comment: What's the difference between get_indexer() and where()?